# Corner case with positional-only parameters in Python 3.8?

Tags: python, arguments, python-3.8, default-arguments, pep570

I am fiddling around with positional-only parameters as specified in [PEP 570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/) and introduced with [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters), and I was just wondering about a specific corner case.

Let's say I define a function as follows (no matter whether that is good design or makes any sense at all):

```py
def func(p1, p2=None, p3=None, /): 
    print(p1, p2, p3)
```

So there is one required parameter (`p1`), followed by two optional parameters (`p2` and `p3`). I can call the function with just `p1`, `p1` and `p2` or `p1` and `p2` and `p3`:

```
func(1)       # 1, None, None
func(1, 2)    # 1, 2, None
func(1, 2, 3) # 1, 2, 3
```

But there is no way I can ever just call it with `p1` and an argument for `p3` while keeping the default for `p2`, as I can not provide keyword arguments:

```
func(1, p3=3)
```

This will of course raise a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: func() got some positional-only arguments passed as keyword arguments: 'p3'
```

I couldn't find any discussion or examples on this case, as all of the examples in [PEP 570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/) just cover a single optional parameter as part of the positional-only arguments:

```
def name(p1, p2, /, p_or_kw, *, kw):
def name(p1, p2=None, /, p_or_kw=None, *, kw):
def name(p1, p2=None, /, *, kw):
def name(p1, p2=None, /):
def name(p1, p2, /, p_or_kw):
def name(p1, p2, /):
```

So my question is: Is that the intended behavior, to have a caller provide multiple optional arguments from left to right, overriding them in a forced order? Is this actually a feature of positional-only arguments?

Comment: `"Is that the intended behavior, to have a caller provide multiple optional arguments from left to right, overriding them in a forced order? Is this actually a feature of positional-only arguments?"` I might not understand you correctly, but not only that is the "intended behavior" of positional-arguments, it's pretty much the definition of it.

Comment: `func(1, p3=3)` directly contradicts the use of `/` in the function's definition as it provides a keyword argument to a function that accepts only positional arguments. The fact the `p2` has a default value is irrelevant

Comment: > func(1, p3=3) directly contradicts the use of /

yeah, that was just to illustrate that just overriding a single default parameter is not possible. I was just confused by multiple defaults in positional-only parameters, but seems to be the behavior you actually want to have. I just found no explicit reference to that behavior.

Comment: With positional-or-keyword parameters, there is a notion of "here are some meaningful defaults, you can override them individually if you want to" whereas with positional-only there are defaults too, but it is more like "here are some defaults, you can override them one by one, but only in the order we tell you too". I guess this is what confused me, that in a positional-only context default parameters have different semantics. But it makes perfect sense, I guess the question is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is that the intended behavior, to have a caller provide multiple optional arguments from left to right, overriding them in a forced order? Is this actually a feature of positional-only arguments?

Not only that is the "intended behavior" of positional-arguments, it's pretty much the definition of it.

`func(1, p3=3)` directly contradicts the use of `/` in the function's signature as it provides a keyword argument to a function that accepts only positional arguments. The fact that `p2` has a default value is irrelevant (though it's pretty much useless as you found).

I will keep looking for an explicit explanation in the documentation but there might not be one. It's basically a straightforward implication of using `/`.

**However**, [PEP570 includes this example](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/#syntax-and-semantics):

```
def name(positional_only_parameters, /, positional_or_keyword_parameters,
         *, keyword_only_parameters):
```

Which suggests we can rewrite `func` as:

```
def func(p1,p3=None, /, p2=None):
    print(p1, p2, p3)
```

Then both of these work:

```
func(1, 3)
func(1, 3, 2)
```

Output is

```
1 None 3
1 2 3
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PyU1TSGtNC9Zo8BQp8DY1i8/L1VHQV9HocAIzNa04lIAgoKizLwSkBKgOBAba3JxgTUBBYBsOFNHwUjz/38A)

Comment: Sure, it would also enable one to call it like `func(1, 3, p2=2)` and even `func(1, p2=2)`.

But that is a different kind of signature then, as it moves `p2` into the positional-or-keyword arguments. 

But you are right anyway, it is the intended behavior. I was just confused by the new semantics that multiple optional arguments have in a positional-only context, but it is actually what you want to have.

Comment: In a positional-or-keyword context, multiple optional arguments can be passed by the caller individually in any combination and order (like cherry picking), whereas in a positional-only context default parameters can be overriden, but only one by one, from left to right, in the order imposed by the signature. That is the point I wasn't grapsing before.

Answer (score 0):

A good example for exactly the described behavior that got me confused is the `eval` Builtin, which has two positional-only optional arguments:

```sh
eval(source, globals=None, locals=None, /)
    Evaluate the given source in the context of globals and locals.

    The source may be a string representing a Python expression
    or a code object as returned by compile().
    The globals must be a dictionary and locals can be any mapping,
    defaulting to the current globals and locals.
    If only globals is given, locals defaults to it.
```

So there is no way to specifiy *only* the `locals`:

```py
>>> eval("1 + 2 + x", locals={'x': 3})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: eval() takes no keyword arguments
```

Positionally, `globals` must be provided first (if `locals` are omitted, they default to the `globals` anyway):

```
>>> eval("1 + 2 + x", {'x': 3}) # globals = locals
6
```

... or, if they should differ:

```
>>> eval("1 + 2 + x", {'x': 3}, {'x': 4})
7
```

So, to answer the question: This is exactly the intended behavior.